# The vba code is executing although the condition is not true

Tags: vba, excel

[image]
The code reads a list of strings from column from "HistoryUrgents" sheet and then it moves into another sheet named "Sheet1" and there it finds them and paints rows containing the strings. It works until it read a second string (it paints correct all rows containing first string). The code just stuck in a continuous loop. If we would force close it by ctrl + break then we got a popup "Run-time error '91'"

As you see on attached screenshot the "c" variable is nothing and although it the `If Not c Is Nothing Then` passed it.

Comment: [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Sorry for that, I've wanted to stressed the fact that c = Nothing and still the condition passes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Do loop your range and cells aren't necessarily referencing Sheet1 - they're referencing the currently active sheet.

Add a dot (period)  before all range & cell references in your 
`With...End With` block.

```
Set c = .Cells.Find(What:=
```

and

```
.Range(.Cells(c.ROW, START_MARK), .Cells(
```

*I haven't been able to test this as you've posted a picture of your code - if you'd posted your code and wrapped it in code tags I could've copied it to a workbook.*

Comment: `.cells.findnext(c)` as well and the `loop while not c is nothing ...` is redundant and unnecessary. Just `loop while not c.address <> firstaddress` is sufficient.

Comment: I'd never even considered that redundancy @Jeeped - I just followed the example given on the MSDN site, but yes - `c` will never be nothing at that stage as it's found the first item and will find it again on the `FindNext` if there's no other matches.

Comment: It's necessary if you change or delete what you find. In that case the `FindNext` will not loop back to the first. However, in this case nothing changes except some offset cells' interior color so it will loop back to the first.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I didn't know that a dot is necessarily.

Comment: by the way can you review my code? Does it look well?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you're getting run-time error 91 is because you're trying to access the property of an object that doesn't exist. If `c` is `Nothing` then `c.Address` doesn't exist. I don't know why this isn't throwing an error automatically, are you doing something to override the error handler or to suppress pop-up messages?

My suggestion would be to move your `c.Address <> firstAddress` check into the body of the loop.

Eg.

```
Do
    If c.Address <> firstAddress Then
        c.Select
        ' ... insert rest of your code ...
        ' ...
    End If
Loop While Not c Is Nothing
```

Comment: This way the code doesn't work at all. In first loop c.Address is the same as firstAddress.